# Get records for current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 Controllers: Sites, Users & Sessions. I have all of the authentication setup, and I set the object current_user in the applications controller once a user logs in. Now, all I want to do is only allow users to see their sites (the sites model has a: "belongs_to :user").

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController

def index
    #this was Site.all, but I changed it. Is there a better way to do this?
    @sites = Site.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    # respond to ... etc
end

# Now, for show, edit and update, I want to ensure the site belongs to the user. How can I add that?
def show
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])
    # respond to ... etc
end
```

If more information is needed (the model, entire controller, etc), just let me know and I'll ad it!

Thanks!

Comment: looks good! I would have done a Site.where but I don't see anything wrong with your approach either. For show/edit etc, you are looking up on id, add a where clause for user id too.

Comment: Well, my main question is how to only let the user edit THEIR site. I tried to add:

def edit
   @site = current_user.sites.find(params[:id])
end

But I get:Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'published_at' in 'order clause': SELECT  `si etc

Comment: change to Site.where(:id => params[:id], :user_id => current_user) ?

Comment: sorry your comment wasnt fully visible until i posted mine, try running rake db:migrate i guess, may be you are missing a migration ;-)

Comment: To allow users edit only their sites you can try cancan or declarative_authorization gem. Railscasts: [cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan), [declarative_authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't catch up your idea very clearly. But seems what you want is something like below:

```
def show
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])

    # check if the site belong to current user
    redirect_to some_user_default_path if @sites.user != @current_user

    # respond to ... etc
end
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that your Models have associations defined like this:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites
end
```

then you should be able do do a simple:

```
  current_user.sites
```

to get all sites associated with this user